# Test of 8 subsequent bytes isn't translated into a single compare instruction

Tags: c++, optimization, comparison, x86-64, memcmp

Motivated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63390851/580083), I compared three different functions for checking if 8 bytes pointed to by the argument are zeros (note that in the original question, characters are compared with `'0'`, not `0`):

```
bool f1(const char *ptr)
{    
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    if (ptr[i])
      return false;
  return true;
}

bool f2(const char *ptr)
{  
  bool res = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    res &= (ptr[i] == 0);
  return res;
}

bool f3(const char *ptr)
{  
  static const char tmp[8]{};
  return !std::memcmp(ptr, tmp, 8);
}
```

Though I would expect the same assembly outcome with enabled optimizations, only the `memcmp` version was translated into a single `cmp` instruction on x64. Both `f1` and `f2` were translated into either a winded or unwinded loop. Moreover, this holds for all GCC, Clang, and Intel compilers with `-O3`.

Is there any reason why `f1` and `f2` cannot be optimized into a single compare instruction? It seem to be a pretty straightforward optimization to me.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/j48366

Comment: Clang trunk actually does optimise f2 to the same code as the memcmp, but weirdly no other version does

Comment: There's also `return ! std::any_of(ptr, ptr+8)`.

Comment: @MSalters Same outcome: https://godbolt.org/z/Gn3xf4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `f1` stops reading at the first non-zero byte, so there are cases where it won't fault if you pass it a pointer to a shorter object near the end of a page, and the next page is unmapped.  **Unconditionally reading 8 bytes can fault in cases where `f1` doesn't encounter UB**, as @bruno points out.  ([Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800739/is-it-safe-to-read-past-the-end-of-a-buffer-within-the-same-page-on-x86-and-x64)).  The compiler doesn't know that you're never going to use it this way; it has to make code that works for every possible non-UB case for any hypothetical caller.

You can fix that by making the function arg `const char ptr[static 8]` (but that's a C99 feature, not C++) to guarantee that it's safe to touch all 8 bytes even if the C abstract machine wouldn't.  Then the compiler can safely invent reads.  (A pointer to a `struct {char buf[8]};` would also work, but wouldn't be strict-aliasing safe if the actual pointed-to object wasn't that.)

---

**GCC and clang can't auto-vectorize loops whose trip-count isn't known before the first iteration.**  So that rules out all search loops like `f1`, even if made it check a static array of known size or something.  (ICC can vectorize some search loops like a naive strlen implementation, though.)

Your `f2` could have been optimized the same as `f3`, to a qword `cmp`, without overcoming that major compiler-internals limitations because it always does 8 iterations.  In fact, **current nightly builds of clang [do optimize `f2`](https://godbolt.org/z/Kjbr7b)**, thanks @Tharwen for spotting that.

**Recognizing loop patterns is not that simple, and takes compile time to look for.**  IDK how valuable this optimization would be in practice; that's what compiler devs need trade off against when considering writing more code to look for such patterns.  (Maintenance cost of code, and compile-time cost.)

The value depends on how much *real world* code actually has patterns like this, as well as how big a saving it is when you find it.  In this case it's a very nice saving, so it's not crazy for clang to look for it, especially if they have the infrastructure to turn a loop over 8 bytes into an 8-byte integer operation in general.

---

In practice, just use `memcmp` if that's what you want; apparently most compilers don't spend time looking for patterns like `f2`.  Modern compilers do reliably inline it, especially for x86-64 where unaligned loads are known to be safe and efficient in asm.

Or use `memcpy` to do an aliasing-safe unaligned load and compare that, if you think your compiler is more likely to have a builtin memcpy than memcmp.

Or in GNU C++, use a typedef to express unaligned may-alias loads:

```
bool f4(const char *ptr) {
   typedef uint64_t aliasing_unaligned_u64 __attribute__((aligned(1), may_alias));
    auto val = *(const aliasing_unaligned_u64*)ptr;
    return val != 0;
}
```

Compiles on [Godbolt with GCC10 -O3](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:17,endLineNumber:29,positionColumn:17,positionLineNumber:29,selectionStartColumn:17,selectionStartLineNumber:29,startColumn:17,startLineNumber:29),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstring%3E%0A%0Abool+f1(const+char+*ptr)%0A%7B++++%0A++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+8%3B+i%2B%2B)%0A++++if+(ptr%5Bi%5D)%0A++++++return+false%3B%0A++return+true%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Abool+f2(const+char+*ptr)%0A%7B++%0A++bool+res+%3D+true%3B%0A++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+8%3B+i%2B%2B)%0A++++res+%26%3D+(ptr%5Bi%5D+%3D%3D+0)%3B%0A++return+res%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Abool+f3(const+char+*ptr)%0A%7B++%0A++static+const+char+tmp%5B8%5D%7B%7D%3B%0A++return+!!std::memcmp(ptr,+tmp,+8)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%0Abool+f4(const+char+*ptr)+%7B%0A++++typedef+uint64_t+aliasing_unaligned_u64+__attribute__((aligned(1),+may_alias))%3B%0A++++auto+val+%3D+*(const+aliasing_unaligned_u64*)ptr%3B%0A++++return+val+!!%3D+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:40,positionColumn:12,positionLineNumber:40,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:37,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:37),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```
f4(char const*):
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rdi], 0
        setne   al
        ret
```

Casting to `uint64_t*` would potentially violate `alignof(uint64_t)`, and probably violate the strict-aliasing rule unless the actual object pointed to by the `char*` was compatible with `uint64_t`.

And yes, alignment *does* matter on x86-64 because the ABI allows compilers to make assumptions based on it.  A faulting `movaps` or other problems can happen with real compilers in corner cases.

- https://trust-in-soft.com/blog/2020/04/06/gcc-always-assumes-aligned-pointers/
- [Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510783/why-does-unaligned-access-to-mmaped-memory-sometimes-segfault-on-amd64)
- [Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605/is-reinterpret-casting-between-hardware-simd-vector-pointer-and-the-correspond/52117639#52117639) is another example of using `may_alias` (without `aligned(1)` in that case because implicit-length strings could end at any point, so you need to do aligned loads to make sure that your chunk that contains at least 1 valid string byte doesn't cross a page boundary.)  Also [Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52112605)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any reason why f1 and f2 cannot be optimized into a single compare instruction (possibly with additional unaligned load)? It seem to be a pretty straightforward optimization to me.

In *f1* the loop stops when `ptr[i]` is true, so it is not always equivalent of to consider 8 elements as it is the case with the two other functions or directly comparing a 8 bytes word if the size of the array is less than 8 (the compiler does not know the size of the array) :

```
f1("\000\001"); // no access out of the array
f2("\000\001"); // access out of the array
f3("\000\001"); // access out of the array
```

For *f2* I agree that can be replaced by a 8 bytes comparison under the condition the CPU allows to read a word of 8 bytes from any address alignment which is the case of the x64 but that can introduce unusual situation as explained in [Unusual situations where this wouldn't be safe in x86 asm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801845/2458991)

Comment: I don't think a compiler should worry about UB when doing optimizations. It's a responsibility of a function user to avoid UB. And, what about `f2`?

Comment: I disagree with you, a compiler cannot introduce UB even to optimize. For *f2* I agree that can be replaced by a 8 byte comparison under the condition there is no alignment problem, I mean it is 'legal' to read a word of 8 bytes from any address

Comment: You're right, I see your point now about UB. That's absolutely true.

Comment: @DanielLangr I edited my answer to speak about *f2*

Comment: @DanielLangr: "introduce UB" is not really the right way to describe it.  UB is a C++ abstract machine concept.  The relevant concept here is inventing reads, which is only allowed if it's known they won't fault.  Unless you check for being within 8 bytes of a page boundary first, you don't know that without knowing alignment.  (Since x86-64 memory protection is based on 4k pages as its finest granularity.)  [Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37800739) - UB in C, well defined in asm and done in practice in `strlen`

Comment: @PeterCordes thank for your remark and the link to your very interesting answer, I edited my answer

Comment: `f2` can *always* be compiled to a qword `cmp`; those caveats apply to `f1`.  In any case where an 8-byte load would fault, the C++ abstract machine would encounter UB because it also touches all 8 bytes.  x86-64 never requires alignment for an 8-byte load.  (Unless you set the AC alignment-checking flag, but C++ implementations can and do assume you haven't done that, especially hand-written memcpy in libc.)

Comment: In fact clang trunk nightly builds *do* optimize `f2` into the same asm as `f3`.

Comment: @PeterCordes not surprising because  *f2* and *f3* have the same (may be bad) behavior in general (I mean independently of the CPU / OS ...)

Comment: It's not *bad* if this function is intended to be called on 8-byte buffers, but you neglected to tell the compiler that (by writing `f1(char*)` instead of `f1(char [static 8])`.  Err that might only be a [C feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array), not C++.  Too bad, sucks for C++ I guess if you can't tell your compiler useful information).

Comment: @PeterCordes: In C++ you can just write `ptr[7];` in `f1`. It's UB when `ptr` is less than 8 elements. Hence the optimizer can subsequently assume that `ptr` has at least 8 elements.

Answer (score -1):

You need to help your compiler a bit to get exactly what you want...  If you want to compare 8 bytes in one CPU operation, you'll need to change your  char pointer so it points to something that's actually 8 bytes long, like a uint64_t pointer.

If your compiler does not support uint64_t, you can use `unsigned long long*` instead:

```
#include <cstdint>

inline bool EightBytesNull(const char *ptr)
{  
    return *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(ptr) == 0;
}
```

Note that this will work on x86, but will not on ARM, which requires strict integer memory alignment.

Comment: That violates strict-aliasing and is thus undefined behaviour.  Only MSVC defines the behaviour of that pointer-cast, out of mainstream x86 compilers.  Do *not* use this, just use memcmp and let it compile to a single `cmp` instruction.

Comment: I am not sure this is safe, since the memory pointed to by `ptr` may not be aligned to `alignof(uint64_t)`.

Comment: @DanielLangr: Oh yes, it's unsafe for that reason as well.  You'd have to use something like GNU C `typedef uint64_t aliasing_unaligned_u64 __attribute__((aligned(1), may_alias))`.  See [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57671930) for an example of such a typedef.

Comment: @DanielLangr and Michael: Misalignment isn't safe on x86 either; auto-vectorization can create code that assumes the ABI-guaranteed alignment.  It's much rarer for it to break, but it's not safe. See [Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47510783), and https://trust-in-soft.com/blog/2020/04/06/gcc-always-assumes-aligned-pointers/.  Since it also violates strict-aliasing, it's very wrong to say "this will work" anywhere except maybe MSVC.  You can `memcpy` 8 bytes into a `uint64_t` and then compare that.

Comment: Oops, meant to link my answer on [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57676035).  See also [Is \`reinterpret\_cast\`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52112605)